# Combine c# and google maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps

I want my browser to run this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Asynchronous Loading</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
        }

        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
      'callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to send the code as a string with an aspx file:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
 
    string s2 = @"


<script>
 function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;";

</script>


<html>
  <head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
   
    <%Response.Write(s2 + "</script>"); %>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="map-canvas">
    
    </div>

     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to run it, it doesn't show the map.. As if it doesn't read the javascript.
Can someone show me what is my problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're right and it doesn't read the JavaScript. So a quick suggestion: I noticed you didn't add the `type` attribute to the script declaration, could you first try and add that, similar to the code below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
```